# How long do scrap and armor packs persist?

Tags: overwatch

How long does scrap metal for Torbjorn stay in the map until it expires?  For his armor packs, do they also last the same amount of time, or do they have a different timer?

Comment: Armor packs seem to last forever, but scrap metal disappears after some time... haven't tested to find out how long.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, scrap seems to last forever until I pick up a certain number of them. I am not certain what this number is since scrap still exists around the map even when I have reached the full 200 scrap limit. The game does indicate where the scrap is located with two downward arrows being shown throughout the map (can even see them through walls), but I have noticed these indicators disappearing after a certain number of picked up scrap (or possibly time, but I am going with number of scrap items - each giving you 25 scrap). As for armor packs, like Powerlord said they last forever as long as your teammates are not hit. Obviously this armor deteriorates first with enemy damage.

The Overwatch wiki pages don't really mention how long scrap lasts on the map without being picked up. Source: http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Scrap

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen scrap disappear, except after changing characters. Perhaps it just doesn't display when you're full? I always throw out armor packs before I get full. It sounds like you're saying how long the *armor* lasts after it gets picked up, rather than how long the armor *packs* remain on the ground. I don't think I've ever seen one of those disappear, either.

Comment: @DCShannon the armor packs on the ground never disappear correct.

Comment: I had them disappear right before me on multiple occasions while scrap hunting, with no connection to the amount i collected. So it IS time based.

Comment: @npst considering how the game has been patched up and updated, that may be the case now.